# C# library for Google Dialogflow V2

Tags: c#, google-api, dialogflow-es, google-api-dotnet-client

It seems there are 2 libraries of C# for Google Dialogflow V2:

Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2/

However, in the document page (https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#v2_client_libraries), C# library is Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2. I can see a lot of codes in Google documents are using this library only. For example https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/delete-intent

I don't know which one should I use to develop?

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google APIs .Net client libray](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client) is designed for use with the Google APIs.  The API classes are generated programmaticlly directly from the discovery services API.

If you're working with **Google Cloud Platform** APIs such as dialog flow, consider using the [Cloud Client Libraries for .NET instead](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet). These are the new and idiomatic .NET libraries targeted specifically at Google Cloud Platform Services.

You could probably use either. However google recommends that you use the Google Cloud client library for Dialog flow api.

**Developer contact beta in production**

I contacted one of the developers on the library to ask his opinion of using the cloud library in production even though its still in beta.

> Yes, it's stable enough to use in a production environment. I'm actually looking at trying to push a bunch of these libraries to GA - mostly we're just missing some reviews and samples.
>
> Dialogflow can be a pain in terms of writing web hooks in C#, because you need to use the protobuf parsing (basically see the docs page) and you can't currently use Dialogflow beta or it spits out enum values we can't parse. Outside of web hooks, it should be fine :)

Comment: I can see the Google Clould Dialogflow V2 is still beta. Should we use it for production now?

Comment: Google leaves most of their libraries in beta forever.   I am personally confident enough to say that you are fine using it in production.   However dialogflow itself is under development there may be breaking changes in the future you should probably check before updating the packages

Comment: Check update i contacted one of the lead developers on the project for you to see if he felt it could be used in production.

Comment: Do you know why does Google publish both Google API Dialogflow and Google Cloud Dialogflow?

Comment: As i mentioned the first library is generated programmaticly since around 2012.  When ever a new api comes up in discovery services it will be generated.    I am not sure why they decided to create the Cloud library rather than just improve upon what they already had

Answer (score 2):

You should use `using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;` as it used in the [Listing and Deleting Intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/delete-intent#list-intent-csharp) documentation, that you refer to. Since you are going to take examples from the examples already provide on [GitHub code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/dialogflow/api/DialogflowSamples/IntentManagement.cs), you will have to have the same libraries.

Comment: Your answer was my thought, but after investigating more (explored the APIs Explorer of Google at [link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dialogflow/v2/dialogflow.projects.agent.intents.list)) I see we can use the Google.Apis.Dialogflow.v2:
`var scopedCreds = creds.CreateScoped(DialogflowService.Scope.CloudPlatform, DialogflowService.Scope.Dialogflow);
 var service = new DialogflowService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
 {
        HttpClientInitializer = scopedCreds
 }).Projects.Agent.Intents.List($"projects/{ProjectId}/agent");`

Comment: Yes, but if you go to the [documentation link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dialogflow/v2/dialogflow.projects.agent.intents.list) from the link you shared, you will see that all the example codes are using `using Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2;`. Check the [DialogflowSamples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/dialogflow/api/DialogflowSamples), procided by Google. Also you can check the [Google API don net client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Src/Generated), you can see the API of Dialogflow V2 for C#.